# How to accept multiple answers that depend on each other?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

My example is [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39222/how-do-i-break-a-film-camera-in-order-to-get-double-exposures). It's asking how to modify a film camera. The first answer describes how to do it, but isn't particularly clear without a picture. Another answer has pictures in reference to the first answer. I don't think the top answer quite cuts it without the second answer, but the second answer relies on the first answer. I need to amalgamate the answers somehow...

Comment: Oh, that one. I did not want to repeat Stan's words in my answer, as he explained it well enough already. Click on his answer, I say.

Answer (score 3):

It's really up to you.  Unfortunately only one answer can be marked as the answer.  Pick whichever you think is the most helpful.  You can vote up both answers which will give them both 10 rep, just only one will get the 15 rep for the answer.  Not really a big deal either way.  You can also make a comment for whichever you don't select to thank them as well.

Comment: And it is not mandatory to Accept any answer, when there is no complete single answer that earns it. Just let it hang a couple of months and then take a fresh look at it, if you feel like it.

Comment: And if you really don't like any of the answers or find an answer yourself that is better, it is perfectly fine to post your own answer and mark that as answer (though you don't get a rep bonus for answering your own question I don't think.)